# Is it possible to run <jsp:include> run after / async with the other html in a jsp?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In this case, I have navigation that load so long.

In this code below. there's an include of other jsp "Side Navigation".

Is it possible to run "side navigation" async with the other html body tag ? or is it posible to make "side navigation" run after the other html show?

Expectation : "Welcome" wording show before / async the navigation finished loading

```
<body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
        <div class="main_container">

            
            <jsp:include page='_Side_Navigation.jsp'></jsp:include>

            <div class="right_col" role="main">

                <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top: 60px;">Welcome</div>
                
            </div>

            <jsp:include page='_Footer_Note.jsp'></jsp:include>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You could try using JSTL's  <c:import> tag  , maybe that will do what you want to do.

Comment: @rickz can you show me how to implement <c:import> because it's using url right ? not a page

Comment: @rickz <c:import  url="/WEB-INF/_Side_Navigation.jsp"/> add something like this, become error 500 in the main page

Comment: I  tested my import tag idea. Sorry, it doesn't work.  The only idea that I could come up with is to use a HTML   iframe.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe   I should explain the reason your url didn't work. It is because you were using a server-relative path.  The tag should be <c:import context="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" url="/WEB-INF/_Side_Navigation.jsp"/>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstration JSP.

```
Here is the first part of page. 
Navigation part will come after a delay for demonstration.<br>
<iframe id="nav" title="nav" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/nav"> 
 </iframe>
Here is the last part of page.
```

I mapped my Navigation file in my web app's web.xml file.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myNav</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/nav.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>myNav</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/nav</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my nav.jsp file, that I used for testing.

```
<%!
    String pause() throws InterruptedException  {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return "imported from nav.jsp after 2 second delay";
    }

%>
<%=pause()%>
```

If you didn't  have your nav file in your WEB-INF folder, then you wouldn't have to map it.
In this solution, the browser makes two requests. One request for the main page and another request for the iframe.